# Batch) Value for '/c' option cannot be more than 253 characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I'm trying to move the file to the desired path using the Windows batch script. (.bat)
However, this error occurs and the code is not performed.

> ```
> value for '/c' option cannot be more than 253 characters
> ```

I haven't found a way to solve this. How can I fix this code?

```
forfiles /p %sourceDir% /d %date% /c "cmd /c if exist %backupDir%\@file ( echo @file 'Backup File Found' ) else ( if exist %targetDir%\@file ( echo @file 'Target File Found' ) else ( if /i @ext==\"partial\" ( echo @file 'Download is in progress' ) else ( copy @file %targetDir% ) ) )"
```

Comment: Shorten the code to less than 253 characters for the `/c` option. The error message seems to be very clear.

Comment: The above sentences are all necessary functions, so I can't take them out. Is there any way to use more than 253 characters?

Comment: No, there isn't. You need to rethink the logic of what you're doing and write it differently. As you've not explained what you're trying to do, it's difficult to provide you with an alternate solution.

Comment: `forfiles /p %sourceDir% /d %date% /c "cmd /c helper.bat @file"`, where `helper.bat` contains your code to do for each result of `forfiles`. No size restrictions, proper formatting for readability. Inside `helper.bat` reference `@file` as `%~1` and `@ext` as `%~x1`

Comment: If you have an issue with the length of your command line, and clearly the length you've submitted does not appear to be of that size, the first thing I'd have to ask is the exact content of `%sourceDir%`, `%backupDir%`, and `%targetDir%`!

Comment: Do you absolutely need all that verbose output? Seems like a single Robocopy command could just copy the file for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks to you, it was very helpful.